# Response in antichess to 1. e3 b5 2. Bxb5 Bb7

Tags: opening, chess-variants, losing

I've been playing a lot of blitz Giveaway Chess (aka Antichess, etc; a chess variant in which capturing is compulsory, the goal is to lose all the pieces or be stalemated, there is no castling, and pawns may promote to any piece, including the king) online.

Some 1700-1800 players respond to 1. e3 by forcing the bishop out with 1...b5, then fianchetto their bishop, to capture the g2 pawn and the h1 rook while white's bishop takes the d pawn, the king, the f pawn and then the knight. After black gives away his queen on d2, with white capturing it with his king, black then gives away his bishop on f3, with white capturing it with his queen. Then, black moves his remaining knight to d7 to protect his dark-square bishop (white's queen threatens this bishop, and if black is forced to capture with a rook, that rook will become a "loose cannon"). White captures the bishop with his queen, and black recaptures with the knight. (Variations in the order of captures are possible, but most other deviations from this opening lead to an instant win for one of the players.)

I think a lot of players play this position as black because it leaves white with many more dangerous minor pieces that are difficult to safely eliminate, poorly developed, and with a surplus of pawns. However, stronger players as white are usually able to take advantage of black's connected rooks and win the game. When I played this opening as black against a 2000+ rated player, he informed me that the position was in fact losing for black. But when I face this position as white, I lose more often than I win.

Can anyone help me find a line for white that is winning? I've tried to open up the rook on the g-file by attacking the two remaining pawns with my dark-squared bishop, but I am usually too slow.